# Mockito When does (not) work

Tags: java, gwt

I am trying to write a test for GWTP presenter, but for some reason mockito when() will not trigger. I stubbed method to return a mock, but it returns null, because as I said method when() is not working (or so I assume). Any ideas?

My unit test:

```
@RunWith(JukitoRunner.class)
public class PresenterATest {

    @Inject
    PresenterA presenterA;

    PresenterA presenterASpy;

    @Mock
    ColumnProperties columnProperties;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws ActionException {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        presenterASpy = spy(presenterA);
    }

    @Test
    public void presenterTest() {
        setUpColumnPropertiesMock();

        when(presenterASpy.getSelectedColumn()).thenReturn(columnProperties);

        // adjust colors intervals with slider
        presenterA.saveColumnIntervals(Arrays.asList(45.55, 59.9, 70.05, 100.15),
                Arrays.asList("#e9a8ff", "#d3ffa6", "#ffffa6", "#a8d4ff", "#ffbca6"));      
    }

    private void setUpColumnPropertiesMock() {
        when(columnProperties.getName()).thenReturn("col1");
    }
}
```

Presenter:

```
public class PresenterA {

    @Inject
    Settings settings;

    public ColumnProperties getSelectedColumn() {
        return settings.getSelectedColumn();
    }

    public void saveColumnIntervals(List<Double> intervals, List<String> colors) {
        ColumnProperties columnProperties = getSelectedColumn();

        columnProperties.setIntervalList(intervals); //Nullpointer here, because getSelectedColumn() returns null
        columnProperties.setColorList(colors);
    }
}
```

Comment: you configure the *spy* to return the `columnProperties` but you call the method on the *mock* (which you wrapped into the spy). But the mock does not know that is is wrapped inside a *spy*.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're trying to say. `you call the method on the mock` What do you mean by this? The method I am calling `saveColumnIntervals` is not called on mock, inject presenter class calls it. Can you explain more please?

Comment: I assumed that spy'ing on injected class (current instance of that class in other words) I can stub any method I want, I think it used to work this way for my other presenter tests...but now I have to use spy object to call `saveColumnIntervals`. Why is that?

Comment: you can spy,but you have to use the spy instances, not the wrapped instance.